# MySQL query return nothing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT a.hinh, cate.ten
FROM (
      SELECT * FORM pro WHERE pro.id IN ( 20, 21 )
     ) AD a
INNER JOIN cate c
ON a.cateid = c.cate.id
```

But

```
SELECT a.hinh, cate.ten
FROM pro AS a
INNER join cate c
on a.cateid = c.cate.id
```

Outputs the correct result.

Can you please suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide sample data???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your above will give you error. You have misspelled `AS` as `AD`. Also there is no need to use a sub-query when you can do it directly like this:

```
SELECT a.hinh, cate.ten
  FROM pro as a
 INNER JOIN  cate
    ON a.cateid = cate.id 
 WHERE a.id IN (20,21)
```

Also, your query is not returning anything only when `ID` 20 and 21 is not available in the table `cate`. If you want to get records even when `ID` 20 and 21 is not available in the table `cate`, you can use `LEFT JOIN` for that:

```
SELECT a.hinh, cate.ten
  FROM pro as a
  LEFT JOIN cate
    ON a.cateid = cate.id 
 WHERE a.id IN (20,21)
```

This will return records from the table `pro` but will return `NULL` for in the table `cate` for `ID` 20 and 21.

Comment: can you explain us how is your query logically diffrent from above one.. i mean this will solve OP problem i dont think so?

Comment: `as` i think is miss spelled only ... i m still not convinced friend...i think both are same...your second query retur all row of table 1 which i m not sure that OP want it or not

Comment: @user2424766 - Glad! What was you actual problem BTW?